# Discord not accessing message.content

Tags: python, discord

I have encountered this problem where the discord api is not accessing my bot content after it has been sent. Down below is my code.

```
import discord
import random

TOKEN = 'SECRET'

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():

    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split("#")[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f' {username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.channel.name == '║bot':
        if user_message.lower() == 'hello':
            await message.channel.send(f'hello {username}!')
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == 'bye':
            await message.channel.send(f'see you later {username}!')
        elif user_message.lower() == "!random":
            response = f'This is your random number: {random.randrange(100)}'
            await message.channel.send(response)
            return

client.run(TOKEN)
```

here is the output:

```
 KaoGaming:  (║bot)
 KaoGaming:  (║bot)
 KaoGaming:  (║bot)
```

As you can see, the message is not identified.

I need the output to look sort of like this:

```
 KaoGaming: hello (║bot)
 KaoGaming: bye (║bot)
 KaoGaming: !random (║bot)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be related to missing the intents:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```